# ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi with apache in ubuntu

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

First of all I have to tell you that I have already seen many solutions for this question. And I have tried most of them. But still could not resolve the issue. So I'm posting it again. 
Please find my 000-default.conf for apache

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr
WSGIPythonPath /home/test-admin/Documents/web_project:/home/test-admin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>

Alias /static /home/test-admin/Documents/web_project/static
<Directory /home/test-admin/Documents/web_project/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/test-admin/Documents/web_project/website>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess test-collection 
WSGIProcessGroup test-collection
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/test-admin/Documents/web_project/website/wsgi.py
ServerName www.test-collection.com
ServerAlias test-collection.com
ServerAdmin admin@test-collection.com
```

sys.prefix

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/usr'
>>>
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

path = r'/home/test-admin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

path = r'/home/test-admin/Documents/web_project'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

sys.stderr.write('\n'.join(sys.path))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "website.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And django installed in path

> r'/home/test-admin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'

and output for ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffccd7d1000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f0eeb607000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0eeb3e8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0eeaff7000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0eeadda000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0eeabd6000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f0eea9d3000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0eea635000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0eebdbe000)
```

so I think mod_wsgi is installed for python 2.7. And tried printing sys.path in the error log and it's coming correctly I guess. Please find the error.log below.

```
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] /usr/lib/python2.7
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] /home/test-admin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] [remote 192.168.2.115:44840] mod_wsgi (pid=4021): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/test-admin/Documents/web_project/website/wsgi.py'.
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] [remote 192.168.2.115:44840] mod_wsgi (pid=4021): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/test-admin/Documents/web_project/website/wsgi.py'.
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] [remote 192.168.2.115:44840] Traceback (most recent call last):
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] [remote 192.168.2.115:44840]   File "/home/test-admin/Documents/web_project/website/wsgi.py", line 23, in <module>
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] [remote 192.168.2.115:44840]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 [wsgi:error] [pid 4021:tid 140595830531840] [remote 192.168.2.115:44840] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

I'm not using any virtual environment. Please find the version info below

1. Django 1.11.13
2. Python 2.7.15
3. Apache 2.4.29
4. Ubuntu 18.04

Can you please help me solve this issue. I've spend almost one day trying to solve this issue. Thank you in advance. Please let me know if I'm missing any information here.

Comment: write a small script. Do the setup you have done in wsgi.py. Then try to import only django. Then django.core. Then django.core.wsgi. Run it and see what happens.

Comment: I tried with another small project. But the issue persists. In all imports I'm getting import error, even after appending the path to sys.path. This time i copied it into /var/www and changed 000-default.conf and added only `ServerName`, `ServerAlias`, `DocumentRoot`, `WSGIPythonPath` and `WSGIScriptAlias `. I changed the path /var/www as I'm getting 403 Forbidden error when the project is in my home directory.